# How can a width be different on my live website and on my local machine?

Tags: html, css

The width of the entire website content gets smaller by about 300px when viewing locally (file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/X/Web/index.html) in opposed to viewing on a live website. I'm viewing the same html file on Chrome. Both have identical css and javascript.

What are the possible scenarios that's causing this problem? I've been trying everything to debug but I cannot find out what the problem is.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does it also happen in Firefox/IE?

If not, then maybe this is a really stupid answer, but it happened to me a few times :$..

On Chrome, you can set zoom for a particular URL.

Have you tried to reset the zoom level for the online site as well as the local site

Chrome -> View -> Actual size...

Otherwise, look on a different PC/Mac running Chrome.. Does it also happen on that machine? If not, its probably a bad Chrome Plugin

Hope it helps!